# Wrong examples in numpy indexing documentation?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

On the numpy indexing [page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html), there is a warning paragraph

> The definition of advanced indexing means that x[(1,2,3),] is fundamentally different than x[(1,2,3)]. The latter is equivalent to x[1,2,3] which will trigger basic selection while the former will trigger advanced indexing. Be sure to understand why this occurs.

I tried to run the following code

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(3*4).reshape((3, 4))
y = x[(1, 2)]
z = x[(1, 2),]

print("base:", x.base, y.base, z.base)
print("id:", id(x.base), id(y.base), id(z.base))
print(np.shares_memory(x, y), np.shares_memory(x, z))
```

and got the results as

```
base: [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11] None None
id: 4299634928 4297628200 4297628200
False False
```

It seems that `y` doesn't return a [view](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html#term-view) and thus `x[(1, 2)]` can't be a basic indexing because

> All arrays generated by basic slicing are always views of the original array.

Is it a mistake in the documentation? Or did I misunderstand somewhere?

Comment: Better test / validate this with **`x.flags`** and if **`OWNDATA: False `**, such an object still **remains** ( since it's original mode of instantiation ) **a view** onto some zone of the underlying numpy array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y` isn't a view because it's a scalar, not an array. All *arrays* generated by basic slicing are always views of the original array.

Comment: @kwunlyou: If you found the answer to be helpful, you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).